# How do you generate F# code using its AST?

Tags: f#, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to generate F# code for a .fs file using the abstract syntax tree. I am able to generate a .cs file using the Roslyn API. Here is an example [riak.cs](https://gist.github.com/ctaggart/0fa68caadd4839a9d2de) file that the unit tests generate based on the [riak.proto](https://github.com/ctaggart/froto/blob/master/test/riak.proto). I would like to do the same thing in F#. I do not want to create a type provider yet. Does anyone have any examples using [FSharp.Compiler.Service](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/), possible with [Fantomas](https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I totally agree with Tomas' answer. You need the latter half of Fantomas pipeline. Here is some relevant information.

- FSharp.Compiler.Service's [AST module](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service/blob/master/src/fsharp/ast.fs#L1487) consists of relevant ASTs and other utility functions for creating AST nodes, which might be helpful for you.
- In Fantomas project, there is [`formatAST`](https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas/blob/master/src/Fantomas/CodeFormatter.fs#L347) function that takes an AST as an input and output a source code string.

Comment: Finally had time to follow up with this. My blog post is here: http://blog.ctaggart.com/2014/09/generating-f-code-using-its-ast.html

Answer (score 9):

Fantomas is certainly the right thing to look at here. If you want to generate F# source code, you basically need two things:

1. Build the AST that represents the source code you want to build. To do that, you need to use the untyped AST from the F# compiler service. The [untyped syntax tree](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Compiler.Service/untypedtree.html) page documents how you can *process* it, but it should be a good starting point for learning about it. The AST of expressions is defined by the [SynExpr type](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler.Service/blob/13982fa12e0bacaa91e16cced40776fbeb1f77ff/src/fsharp/ast.fs#L454).
2. Once you build the AST, you need to format it. The F# compiler does not include a pretty printer, but this is exactly what Fantomas does in the [CodePrinter file](https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas/blob/master/src/Fantomas/CodePrinter.fs), so you should be able to copy this & pass your AST to the formatting implemented there. I think [Visual F# PowerTools](https://github.com/fsprojects/VisualFSharpPowerTools) might actually have a newer version of Fantomas, so check that out first.

This answer is all using *untyped* AST, which is probably a good fit for working with syntax of the language. There is also *typed* AST (created after type inference finishes), but that's hard to use and not a good fit here.

Comment: And this gives you F# source from an untyped AST?  I thought you needed a CodeDOM provider of some sort.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes - Fantomas is a tool that re-formats your F# code and it implements a pretty printer that does this. So, yes, this gives you F# code. CodeDOM is another option, but it generates very ugly code (because it has been designed for C#/VB)

Comment: Fantomas accepts an AST as input, not source?  Does it parse source into an AST first, and then re-emit it?

Comment: It accepts source, uses the compiler to build AST and then pretty prints the AST. So a part of it does what the OP needs here. How else could it work? [Regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Well, no, I wouldn't use regular expressions.  Having an AST is certainly a very cool bonus, but I doubt that's how online code prettifiers work; you're essentially re-implementing a compiler (well, the lexing and parsing part of it, anyway).  Visual Studio gets the AST for free, so they might as well use it for their code formatting.

Comment: Having the AST is the only reasonable way to do this... But yes, I suppose it could be written using an ad-hoc set of rules that process a list of lines represented as strings and sometimes get it right :-)